# How to select matching text in a string and replace it using jQuery/JS

Tags: jquery

I have various `{{ context }}` in an html doc:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{ context_1  }} consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. {{ context_2 }} Ut enim ad minim veniam.<p>
```

How can I add a `<span>` class around all the variables in curly brackets to give

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>{{ context_1 }}</span> consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span>{{ context_2 }}</span> Ut enim ad minim veniam.<p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overload of `.replace` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) to specify a regular expression.

Combine with `.html()` to get and set the html.

There are various different ways to use replace with a regex, here's a couple:

```
.replace(/{{.*}}/g, "<span>$&</span>")
.replace(/({{.*}})/g, "<span>$1</span>")
.replace(/{{(.*)}}/g, "<span>$1</span>")  //if you also want to remove the `{{}}`
```

```js
$("p").html((i, html) => {
  return html.replace(/({{.*}})/g, "<span>$1</span>")
});
```

```css
p>span { color: pink }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{ context_1  }} consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. {{ context_2 }} Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{ context_1  }} consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. {{ context_2 }} Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I exclude `{{ content }}` in a tag element, e.g. `<a href="{{ content }}"></a>`?

Comment: Change the regex: `, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>"`

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't that just wrap the result in `<a>` not exclude results within `<a>`?

Comment: You'll need to provide an example output for what *"exclude results"* means

Comment: Ah, you mean, if the text is `<p>Lorem ipsum <a href='{{context1}}'>dolor</a></p>` - in that case the same regex, but instead of `$("p").html` loop through all the children elements that are just text elements.